# Use Ruby to parse a Tcl DSL

Tags: ruby, parsing, tcl, dsl, method-missing

I would like to be able to parse some Tcl code where arguments are not surrounded by strings.

Consider this tcl code:

```
proc foo {name} {
  puts "Foo --> $name"
}    

foo bar
```

For those unfamiliar with Tcl, `foo` is the method name and `bar` is the argument (quotes are optional in Tcl).

The previous code will output:

```
Foo --> bar
```

Is it possible to parse *exactly* the same input using ruby (`bar` remains unquoted)?

The equivalent ruby code is:

```
def foo(name)
  puts "Foo --> #{name}"
end

tcl = <<-TCL.gsub(/^\s+/, "").chop
  foo bar
TCL
instance_eval(tcl)
```

Of course that fails when it reaches `bar` since it's expected it to be quoted.

I've tried tinkering with `method_missing`

```
def method_missing(meth, *args)
    puts meth.to_s + " --> args.to_s
end
```

but it parses in reverse order:

```
to_hash --> []
bar --> []
foo --> [nil]
```

Does anyone have a clean solution to this type of problem. I'd like to avoid tokenizing the strings since reading the data in by calling a method requires minimal work compared to lexical analysis. But if I'm trying to do something that's not possible, I'd like to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doesn't work for you because `.puts` method returns `nil` instead of string:

```
irb(main):003:0> puts "42"
42
=> nil
```

I really don't know why `to_hash` appears in this `method_missing` but it works:

```
def foo(name)
  puts "Foo --> #{name}"
end

def method_missing(meth, *args)
     meth.to_s unless meth.to_s  == "to_hash"
end

tcl = <<-TCL.gsub(/^\s+/, "").chop
  foo bar
TCL

instance_eval(tcl)

=> Foo --> bar
```

Comment: Dang, I was so close at getting it. Thanks for input. Can anyone chime in on where `to_hash` is coming from?

Comment: Tcl doesn't use anything like `nil`; the concept is split between the empty string (the result of Tcl's `puts`) and non-existance of variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation that try to make the syntax near to the TCL syntax.

```
class TCL
  class << self
    alias run instance_eval
    def proc(n, &b)
      self.class.__send__(:define_method, n, &b)
    end
    def method_missing(n, *a, &b)
      n.to_s
    end
  end
end

TCL.run do

  proc(:foo) { |name|
    puts "Foo --> #{name}"
  }

  foo bar

end

# prints Foo --> bar
```

Comment: I had to change your braces in the block to do/end due to precedence. And then I still was getting a bug with the `define_method` which I couldn't figure out. Want to elaborate a little more?

Comment: @elmt, I made changes and now I tested. There were many things wrong. Now it works.