# Ruby blocks with method_missing

Tags: ruby, parsing, tcl, dsl, method-missing

*Note, this is a follow up to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736351/use-ruby-to-parse-a-tcl-dsl)*.

I'm trying to parse the following Tcl code:

```
foo bar {
  biz buzz
}
```

In Tcl, `foo` is the method name, `bar` is the argument, and the rest is a "block" to be processed by [`eval`](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/eval.html).

Now here is my current implementation to this:

```
def self.foo(name, &block)
  puts "Foo --> #{name}"
  if block
    puts "block exists"
  else
    puts "block does not exist"
  end
end

def self.method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
  p meth
  p block
  meth.to_s &block
end

tcl = <<-TCL.gsub(/^\s+/, "").chop
  foo bar {
    biz buzz
  }
TCL

instance_eval(tcl)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
:bar
#<Proc:0x9e39c80@(eval):1>
Foo --> bar
block does not exist
```

In this example, when the block is passed up to the `foo` method, it does not exist. Yet in `method_missing` it does exist (at least it appears to exist). What's going on here?

Note, I am aware of ruby's precedence of parentheses and realize this works:

```
foo (bar) {
  biz buzz
}
```

However, I want to have the parentheses omitted. So is this possible in ruby (without lexical analysis)?

Comment: Note that in Tcl you'd be more likely to process a “block” passed to a procedure with `uplevel`, but that's a concept which doesn't map to Ruby at all; the two languages simply have different concepts of what scoping means.

Comment: Donal, I understand that. Fortunately what I have to parse is as simple as this, nothing more.

Comment: That's partially why I only posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (I marked the lines I changed):

```
def self.foo args                  # changed
  name, block = *args              # changed
  puts "Foo --> #{name}"
  if block
    puts "block exists"
  else
    puts "block does not exist"
  end
end

def self.method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
  p meth
  p block
  return meth.to_s, block          # changed
end
```

That way, block will exist.

Comment: Wow this is great! Thanks for not repeating what I already knew and proving that if there's a will, there's a way.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `method_missing`. You simply can't omit parentheses when passing block along with some parameters. In your case, Ruby will try to call `bar` method with block as an argument, and the result of it all will be passed to `foo` method as a single argument.

You can try this yourself by simplifying the method call (all the metaprogramming just obscures the real problem in your case):

```
# make a method which would take anything
def a *args, &block
end

# try to call it both with argument and a block:
a 3 {
  4
}
#=>SyntaxError: (irb):16: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting $end
#   from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution I've found is to just `gsub` the string before processing it.

```
tcl = <<-TCL.gsub(/^\s+/, "").chop.gsub('{', 'do').gsub('}', 'end')
  foo bar {
    biz buzz
  }
TCL
```